Deep link Revolut app to Payments page with parameters
i'm looking for guidence on implementing a deep link in Revolut app.
For example, "revolut://app/payments" opens the Payments page in the app.
Is there a way to open the payments page with pre-populated fields, for example, for bank transfer?
For instance, include sortcode, account number, name and amount. So the Revolut user would only have to validate the data and click pay.
Thank you
